# Hibernate with JPA won't create table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to create a table by using Hibernate + JPA. The problem is that whenever I run my code it won't create any tables. I have created already an empty database. I use Hibernate + JPA + HSQL + Maven.

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
```

```
<!-- Provider of Persistence -->
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

<!-- Classes, in which JPA-Annotations are read -->
<class>com.mysite.warehousebase.base.ProductData</class>

<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:Warehouse"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />

  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>

  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my productData.java code:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class ProductData extends Entityclass {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/*
//Product Addition Time
@NotNull
@Column(name = "added", nullable = false)
private Date productAdded;*/

//Product Name
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productname", nullable = false)
private String productName;

//Product Description
@Column(name = "productdescription", nullable = true)
private String productDescription;

//Product Size
@Column(name = "productsize", nullable = true)
private String productSize;

//Product Amount
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productamount", nullable = false)
private int productAmount;

//Product Left
//Attribute to be calculated in own method
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productleft", nullable = false)    
private int productLeft;

//Product buy price
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productprice", nullable = false)     
private double productPrice;

//Total cost
//Attribute to be calculated in own method
@NotNull
@Column(name = "totalproductprice", nullable = false)
private double totalProductPrice;

//Product sell price
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productsellprice", nullable = false)
private double productSellPrice;

//Product sale
//Attribute to be calculated in own method
@NotNull
@Column(name = "totalsellprice", nullable = false)    
private double totalSellPrice;

//Difference between cost and sale (total)
//Attribute to be calculated in own method
@NotNull
@Column(name = "buyselldifference", nullable = false)    
private double buySellDifference;

//Product status; ordered, at warehouse, reserved.
//Attribute to be calculated in own method
@NotNull
@Column(name = "productstatus", nullable = false)    
private String productStatus;

@Column(name = "reservedproducts", nullable = true)
private int reservedProducts;

/**
 * All Setters and Getters
 * 
 */

/**
 * @return the productName
 */
public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

/**
 * @param productName the productName to set
 */
public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

/**
 * @return the productDescription
 */
public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}

/**
 * @param productDescription the productDescription to set
 */
public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription;
}

/**
 * @return the productSize
 */
public String getProductSize() {
    return productSize;
}

/**
 * @param productSize the productSize to set
 */
public void setProductSize(String productSize) {
    this.productSize = productSize;
}

/**
 * @return the productAmount
 */
public int getProductAmount() {
    return productAmount;
}

/**
 * @param productAmount the productAmount to set
 */
public void setProductAmount(int productAmount) {
    this.productAmount = productAmount;
}

/**
 * @return the productLeft
 */
public int getProductLeft() {
    return productLeft;
}

/**
 * @param productLeft the productLeft to set
 */
public void setProductLeft(int productLeft) {
    this.productLeft = productLeft;
}

/**
 * @return the productPrice
 */
public double getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

/**
 * @param productPrice the productPrice to set
 */
public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

/**
 * @return the totalProductPrice
 */
public double getTotalProductPrice() {
    return totalProductPrice;
}

/**
 * @param totalProductPrice the totalProductPrice to set
 */
public void setTotalProductPrice(double totalProductPrice) {
    this.totalProductPrice = totalProductPrice;
}

 /**
 * @return the productSellPrice
 */
public double getProductSellPrice() {
    return productSellPrice;
}

/**
 * @param productSellPrice the productSellPrice to set
 */
public void setProductSellPrice(double productSellPrice) {
    this.productSellPrice = productSellPrice;
}

/**
 * @return the totalSellPrice
 */
public double getTotalSellPrice() {
    return totalSellPrice;
}

/**
 * @param totalSellPrice the totalSellPrice to set
 */
public void setTotalSellPrice(double totalSellPrice) {
    this.totalSellPrice = totalSellPrice;
}

/**
 * @return the buySellDifference
 */
public double getBuySellDifference() {
    return buySellDifference;
}

/**
 * @param buySellDifference the buySellDifference to set
 */
public void setBuySellDifference(double buySellDifference) {
    this.buySellDifference = buySellDifference;
}

/**
 * @return the productStatus
 */
public String getProductStatus() {
    return productStatus;
}

/**
 * @param productStatus the productStatus to set
 */
public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
    this.productStatus = productStatus;
}

    /**
 * @return the reservedProducts
 */
public int getReservedProducts() {
    return reservedProducts;
}

/**
 * @param reservedProducts the reservedProducts to set
 */
public void setReservedProducts(int reservedProducts) {
    this.reservedProducts = reservedProducts;
}

/**
 * @return the productSection
 */
public ProductSection getProductSection() {
    return productSection;
}

/**
 * @param productSection the productSection to set
 */
public void setProductSection(ProductSection productSection) {
    this.productSection = productSection;
}

public ProductData(){

}

public ProductData(String productName){
    this.productName = productName;
}

}
```

And my main.java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataStructureTest testProduct = new DataStructureTest();
    testProduct.testProductData();
}
```

What is wrong? Why Hibernate won't create a table that is needed? I have tried using hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto with value of "update". It won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. For some reason value of

`property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:Warehouse"`

won't work. So instead of what I did was that I created a database connection which value was following 
`jdbc:hsqldb:file:[folder name]`

This folder name is user defined. So the new code of that particular line would be:

`property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:[folder name]"`

Now everything is running smoothly and tables are created and updated :).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

Also '`transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` is defined in the persistence xml

Comment: Yes I have tried your suggestion but it still won't work. I have    <persistence-unit name="warehousePersistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">, but it still won't work.

Comment: Can you try changing the jdbc url to `jdbc:hsqldb:Warehouse;create=true`